# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in storage/emulated/legacy/download/register.php on line 13

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

el problema es que estoy haciendo una página y estaba trabajando en la página de registro, pero me salió esto: **Fatal error:** Can't use function return value in write context in storage/emulated/legacy/download/register.php on **line 13**.

Esta es la línea de código que contiene el error:

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
```

He intentado varias formas de arreglarlo y funcionan, pero entonces el código no funciona como quiero.

¿Pueden ayudarme?

*PD: Estoy desarrollando en android, con anWriter free y AWD, y utilizo el servidor AndroPHP*

Comment: Me imagino que tu `username` no tiene caracteres especiales, porque al usar trim, estás limpiando una cadena de espacios en blancos y otros caracteres. Solo tendrías que hacer `empty($_POST["username"])` si es eso. Aunque deberías especificar que hace esa consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Este mensaje de error se explica por sí mismo. Significa que estamos intentando usar la función para devolver el valor en el contexto de escritura. También nos dice dónde ocurrió exactamente este error.

Para resolver este error cambia tu código por el siguiente:

```
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
if (empty($username)) {
    // Si $username esta vacio entonces entra.
    // En caso contrario se brincara este if
}
```

Básicamente verificamos que exista el `$_POST['username']`, si es así le hacemos el `trim()` a lo que contenga `username` y si no existe le asignamos el valor vacío, seguido verificamos tal cual con tu `if` pero sin el `trim()`, si `$username` es vacío entonces entra al `if` de lo contrario se brincara lo brincara. Ya será cuestión tuya si le defines un `else{}` a tu `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que según https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php explica que la functión empty antes de php 5.5 solo soportaba variables por lo que empty( trim( $variable ) ); produciría un error en el intérprete entonces lo que debes hacer es verificar que versión de php tiene y actualizarla si puedes claro hacer un respaldo antes de la base de datos y del programa.